# Fixed Width File manipulation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fixed-width

I have a fixed-width file with the following format:

```
5678223313570888271712000000024XAXX0101010006461801325345088800.0784001501.25abc@yahoo.com                                        
5678223324686600271712000000070XAXX0101010006461801325390998280.0784001501.25abcde.12345@gmail.com                             5678123422992299
```

Here's what i tried :

```
import pandas as pd

ColSpecs = [(0,16),(16,31),(31,44),(44,62),(62,70),(70,73),(73,77),(77,127),(127,143)]

df = pd.read_fwf("~/filename.txt",colspecs=ColSpecs,Header=True)
```

Now this surely helps me to convert cleanly in Pandas format. However, the blank(or fixed white spaces) get trimmed off. For Eg: the Email field(#8) has 50 characters set fixed. They get truncated as soon as they're imported to Pandas dataframe.

For the data manipulation, I am creating 3 new fields that are extracted from the values of the previously imported fields.

Final Output file structure:

[(0,16),(16,31),(31,44),(44,62),(62,70),(70,73),(73,77),(77,127),(127,143),(143,153),(153,163),(164,165)]

Since, I haven't found any to_fwf method on dataframes or any other alternative for Pandas -> Flat File (keeping original lengths intact) , I would really appreciate if anyone has a better solution.

P.S. : I read that awk/sed in Unix works better, but still would like to know for Python

Comment: I don't thin so. [From the docs:](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns) `The parser will take care of extra white spaces around the columns so it’s ok to have extra separation between the columns in the file.`. And as far as I can tell, there's no easy way to remove that functionality.

Comment: But in your case, since you need to extract values from the previously imported fields, why not also specify which fields those are? When using `colspecs` you can have overlapping fields. So for instance, `ColSpecs= [(0,16), (1,5), (4,10), (5,7)]` is perfectly valid and will create your subfields of the first 16 characters

Comment: @ALollz : Thanks for the reply. Yes, I think for the extra white spaces, there's no way to retain the original lengths during the import.